# onfling indicator in viewpager android

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am developing an android application in which I am using Tablerow with viewpagerAdapter. 
I need to add an indicator as the user swipes from one page to the other,for which I want to add an horizontal line, just as shown in the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDtm1.jpg

I tried adding the Image(Horizontal line),it fits all the 3 tabs instead of just tab1

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    style="@style/layout_f_w"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        style="@style/layout_wrap"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:clickable="true" >

        <!-- First Tab -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_text"
            style="@style/layout_f_w"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                style="@style/text_title"
                android:text="Tab1" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_text"
            style="@style/layout_f_w"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                style="@style/text_title"
                android:text="Tab2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/third_text"
            style="@style/layout_f_w"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                style="@style/text_title"
                android:text="Tab3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/indicator" />

<ImageView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/h_line" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is the image?...Try using a relative layout.. and set both the horizontal lines . Then set alpha(0) or one according to the page movement. If u can show the horizontal line.. i may be able to explain u better..

Comment: @amal: image is added above.You can also click on the link : http://imgur.com/ZTD7w0e

Comment: okay.... now place three horizontal lines below each tab and set their visibility to gone. And from then set each of them visible when the respective page is selected..

Comment: @amal: Ya..The distance from one tab to other tab is not known,so the image is not fit properly to the tab properly. It either goes to the left end of the tab or the right end of the tab.

Comment: I dont think you need to know the distance...place the three horizontal lines when you design in xml with drag and drop.And set their visibility to gone.. now in run time... update their visibility on or off according to your condition from your viewpageradapter class....

Comment: I tried it.Its not working..

Comment: can i see how you are updating?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

[Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Comment: I have used it.It is bit complex and the text in the tab is longer and it is adding to the next row.So,I tried in different way.It is working perfectly except the indicator.